# Get PID of sending pipe process

Tags: shell, pipe

For

```
$ any-process | receiver
```

Can `receiver` get the PID of the sending process?

Comment: No. There can be several pids connected to the pipe. For example, if I write `{ echo foo; sleep 3; cat /etc/passwd; sleep 5; echo bar; } | myCode`, then all five processes on the left inherit the same write end of the pipe. They use the pipe in turn, only because the subshell runs them consecutively.

Comment: This could be a XY problem, what would "receiver" do wth this pid, for example send a signal once?

Comment: @thanasisp yes, you could monitor for certain output and then send a signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. It could, but it would need to identify the pipe it is connected to, then search all other pid for one connected to that one.

Suppose `receiver` had pid 1730. It could look at `/proc/self/fd/0` (or, more easily, `/proc/self/fd/0`) and see it shows as a symlink to `pipe:[43270]`. `/proc/1730/fdinfo/0`. Then it could discover that `/proc/1729/fd/1` shows as a symlink to `pipe:[43270]`, and on `/proc/1729/fdinfo/1` see it has in flags `01`. Thus, it found a process holding the other end of the pipe.

Please note:

- this is a Linux-specific approach, non-portable and inefficient
- multiple processes may be able to write into that pipe (also, the writing does not need to be at fd 1 at all)
- it is prone to race conditions
- if `any-process` is owned by a different user, `receiver` won'r be able to peek into their file descriptors

If what you want to do is to have two processes communicate in an authenticated way, you should use a unix socket. Through them it is possible via `SO_PASSCRED` option to use an ancillary message of type `SCM_CREDENTIALS` with the pid, uid and gid of the sender. The  credentials  which  the sender specifies are checked by the kernel to ensure it cannot lie (unless it has appropriate capabilities, a root process / CAP_SYS_ADMIN *would* be able to specify a different process id than its own).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way can be achived by redirecting the executing process to file descriptor 3, here is an example of **sleep** command that is piped to **ps** command  :

```
( sleep 100 & echo $!>&3 ) 3>pid | ps -p "$(<pid)"
```

You can check the process of the command sleep :

```
ps -p $(<pid)
```

Comment: What is the purpose for not writing the pid directly to the file?

Comment: The purpose here is that the pid need to be used within the same command and piped to the next command, manipulating a file descriptor is more easy in this use case.